# Opent text file, copy data between two strings, transpose and join

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set that looks like this.

```
random stuff
more random stuff
random, random, random
random, random, random
  - class: pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize
    conf:
      schema_def:
        fields:
        - data_type: STRING
          name: Operation
        - data_type: STRING
          name: SNL_Institution_Key
        - data_type: INTEGER
          name: SNL_Funding_Key
        - data_type: STRING
          name: CUSIP
    id: standardize
  steps:
  steps:
  steps:
  - class: pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize
    conf:
      schema_def:
        fields:
        - data_type: STRING
          name: Operation
        - data_type: INTEGER
          name: Rate_Value_OID
        - data_type: INTEGER
          name: Key_Rate
    id: standardize
  steps:
  steps:
  steps:
```

I am trying to copy/paste all data between `'  - class: pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize'` and `'    id: standardize'`.  I want to include the `'  - class: pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize'` and `'    id: standardize'`.  Finally, I want to transpose and concatenate each row together with commas.  Basically, I want it to look like this image below.

[image]

Here is the code that I am working with.

```
import itertools

with open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AllYAML\\final_result.txt', 'r') as f, open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\AllYAML\\test_out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    while True:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip(" -")
            s = line.split(": ")
            fout.write(": ".join(s[::-1]))
        it = itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: line.strip() != '- class: pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize', f)
        if next(it, None) is None: break
        fout.writelines(itertools.takewhile(lambda line: line.strip() != '- class: pipe.steps.load.Load', it))
```

It seems like that should be pretty close, but something is off here, and I don't know what.

Comment: And what are you getting as output or error message?

Comment: Please don't insert (unreadably small) images with text, include the text instead. Also, consider [ask], be terse in your questions and be specific with your problems. Dumping your whole design isn't terse. "It seems" isn't specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your start and ends are always going to be the same, you can use regex to identify everything in between and then build them to a list and finally save them your destination.

```
with open('final_result.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read()

start = '-class:pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize,'
end = ',id:standardize'

import re
results = re.findall(r'- class: pipe\.steps\.standardize\.Standardize\n    (.*?)id: standardize',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)
prep_results = [i.replace(' ','').split('\n') for i in results]
output = [start+','.join(i)+end for i in prep_results]

with open('final_results.txt','w') as f:
    for line in output:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Output:

```
for i in output:
    print(i)
>>
-class:pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize,conf:,schema_def:,fields:,-data_type:STRING,name:Operation,-data_type:STRING,name:SNL_Institution_Key,-data_type:INTEGER,name:SNL_Funding_Key,-data_type:STRING,name:CUSIP,,id:standardize
-class:pipe.steps.standardize.Standardize,conf:,schema_def:,fields:,-data_type:STRING,name:Operation,-data_type:INTEGER,name:Rate_Value_OID,-data_type:INTEGER,name:Key_Rate,,id:standardize
```

Comment: This works in some cases, but not all.  What is the Start and End can be slightly different, like 'Start', 'Started', 'Starting'.  I'm Googling for a solution for 'Start' + wildcard search for the end of the string.

Comment: It works for the cases you have posted in your question. If you have different start and ends, you are on the right path to look for regex patterns that match them. ;)

Comment: Yeap, yeap.  I need to play around with the regex stuff and learn that better.  I'll get on that right now.  Thanks for all the help with this!!